# NTFS locate and read $MFT from RAW

Tags: winapi, filesystems, ntfs, ntfs-mft

I'm currently trying to programmatically parse the MFT of my hard drive from it's raw data in order to enumerate all files with a specific extension (in a really short time).

I'm following that tutorial to guide myself: [A Programmers View of Raw Filesystem Data Extraction](http://www.campus64.com/digital_learning/data/cyber_forensics_essentials/info_ntfs_forensics.pdf) .

I've successfully opened `\\.\PhysicalDrive0` using `CreateFileA`, and I did locate the first sector of my Windows partition where I found the `BPB`.

My problem is that I'm unable to properly locate the `MFT`.

[image: MFT Logical Cluster number]

As you can see above *(raw data of the first sector of my Windows partition)*, the logical cluster number of the MFT is equal to `0x56a6`.

I then calculated the number of sectors per clusters which is `0x20 (0x20 * 512 = 0x4000 bytes)`.

So logically the MFT is at offset `0x4000 * 0x56a6` which is equal to `0x15a98000`.

And when I seek to that offset and retrieve the first 512 bytes I don't see the expected data which is supposed to start by `FILE` (I just see some random bytes).

I also tried to seek not from the first sector of the partition but the one of the hard drive and it doesn't work too (I guess that's normal).

I guess that I'm missing something, but I don't know what.

I hope I've been clear enough, if you need more details and informations I'll provide them.

Thanks.

Comment: I see that sectors per cluster is 8. Look carefuly at offset 0x0D. Your assumption about 0x15a98000 is totally wrong.

Comment: @user2120666 I did an error when I wrote the topic yes, but even with the right number of sectors per clusters (8) I have the same error. But that time in the retrieved data I'll be able to read `Inval
id partition table.Error loading operating system.Missing op
erating system`.

Comment: Is this partition first partition on the physical disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the definition of `NTFS_BOOT_SECTOR` struct in the document, the offset of `uchSecPerClust` is 3 + 4 + 4 + `sizeof(WORD)`= 0x0D.(Ignore byte alignment)

Or you can uses [`DeviceIoControl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ioapiset/nf-ioapiset-deviceiocontrol) with the [`IOCTL_DISK_GET_DRIVE_GEOMETRY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winioctl/ni-winioctl-ioctl_disk_get_drive_geometry) control code to fill a [`DISK_GEOMETRY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winioctl/ns-winioctl-disk_geometry) structure with information about the drive:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/devio/calling-deviceiocontrol

Another useful control code: [`FSCTL_ENUM_USN_DATA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winioctl/ni-winioctl-fsctl_enum_usn_data)

Comment: Yes I did an error while writing the topic, the `$MFT` offset is 0x56a6000, but that time when I retrieve the data I can read `Invalid partition table.Error loading operating system.Missing operating system`. Thanks I'll try with the DeviceIoControl function.

Comment: But can't I just enumerate the files with a low level approach without using the DeviceIoControl function ?